# Magento: TypeError: N is not a function

Tags: javascript, magento, highcharts

I'm trying to add highcharts to magento, but I get following error

```
TypeError: N is not a function (highcharts.js line 192)
```

My local.xml

```
<adminhtml_mymodule_show>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><file>mymodule/js/highcharts.js</file></action>
        <action method="addJs"><file>mymodule/js/my_charts.js</file></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_mymodule_show>
```

my_charts.js

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]},
            {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]}]
    });
});
```

My view file

```
<div class="entry-edit">
    <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4 class="icon-head head-customer-view">
            <?php echo $this->__('Test header') ?></h4>
    </div>
    <h1><?php echo $this->test; ?></h1>

    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
</div>
```

I checked in Firebug and these files are added inside head tag. I tried also add prototype-adapter.js or using standalone framework but it didn't work- I get every time error from title.

Im using magento 1.9 and highcharts 4.0.4.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Conflict with jQuery and prototype.js?

Comment: Are you able to recreate it as live demo, isolated from magento as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not recognize N in highchart.js. There may be external js that need to be loaded along with highchart.js.

Make sure jQuery is loaded before highchart.js.